# regex returns None on parsing address

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse this particular address through the regex in python.

```
  address = "16220 Scottsdale Road, Suite 100 Scottsdale, AZ 85254"
```

why this regex is returning `None`

```
try:
    print re.search('/[0-9]{1,5} (.*?), (.*?) [a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?/', address)
except:
    None
```

Comment: Remove the `/.../`, no delimiters are necessary

Comment: Enclosure in `/.../` is a Perl thing, not a Python thing.

Comment: Thanks all
Can anyone explain me the significance of '?' along with (.*) even if I remove it the result is same

Comment: For testing your regex https://regex101.com/#python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the leading and trailing slashes and use raw strings instead:

```
>>> re.search(r'[0-9]{1,5} (.*?), (.*?) [a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?', address)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 53), match='16220 Scottsdale Road, Suite 100 Scottsdale, AZ 8>
```

Here is the difference between greedy and non greedy matching (see the matched string):

```
>>> re.search(r'.*?,', "abcd,abcde,abc, f")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='abcd,'>
>>> re.search(r'.*,', "abcd,abcde,abc, f")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 15), match='abcd,abcde,abc,'>
```

Comment: Thanks
Can anyone explain me the significance of '?' along with (.*) even if I remove it the result is same

Comment: @Guru a question mark after `*` implies non-greedy matching